# Check for specific formatting (time and date)

Tags: javascript, date, time

I need to test in **javascript** the following formats (so I have a string and I must check if it's valid or not)

```
XX:XX
```

value must be **two integer** (with **two** digits) separated by **colon**, the first one must be 0-23 and second 0-59 (it's about time).

Second test is about **date**

```
DD.MM.YYYY
```

where DD is 2-digit representation of day, MM month and YYYY year - separated by dots. Can I also check is the **date valid**? So the user couldn't type 45.02.9999 for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished with fairly straightforward RegEx.

The first to test time in 24-hour format would be:

```
/(0[1-9]|1[1-9]|2[1-3]):[0-5][1-9]/.test(yourTime);
```

The second to test date would be:

```
/([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\.(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\.(19[0-9][0-9]|20[0-1][0-9])/.test(yourDate);
```

Which will allow dates up until 31.12.2019.  It's not smart enough to know how many days each month has (i.e. that 31.02.1999 is not a valid date), but should be good enough initial validation for most purposes.

Answer (score 1):

In this post you have all the Regexp that you need.

http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=4&categoryId=5

this is for time:

```
^(([0-1]?[0-9])|([2][0-3])):([0-5]?[0-9])(:([0-5]?[0-9]))?$
```

this is for date:

```
^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]).([1][0-12]|[0][1-9]).(19|20)\d\d$
```

you can try this regexp in http://www.rubular.com/

Comment: A regex can't check the validity. There is no way a regex can catch an invalid date such as `29.02.2011`

Comment: @Stephen P You haven't heard of Gregorian Compatible Regular Expressions? :P

Answer (score 0):

Use a two pass approach. First use a regex to check the general structure of the string to make sure it has the correct delimiters and digits in the right place. In the second pass you can use `indexOf()` to find delimiters and `substring()` to extract the numbers in each position. Then use `n = str * 1` to convert to a number and check the range `n >=0 && n <=23` in the first case.

The two pass approach means you can have a simpler regex and more readable code.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to split the string into its components then populate a date object with the result to check validity.